# IntelliJ dependency issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, dependencies, package

I've recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ and now I am working on my first project using this IDE

As normal I guess I went on and divided my project into multiple packages only to find out that IntelliJ offers modules,packages and also regular directories for project organisation. I just assumed that modules are equivalent to eclipse packages and IntelliJ packages replace directories in the Source Root module, so I didn't care about that. But when I started writing code in the main class (located in a package in the source root module) i couldn't access any classes located in other modules even after I've manually set up the dependencies.

I'm definitely missing something because if I create a regular directory outside the source root module and move it there afterwards everything is fine, but is annoying that I can't directly create the folder inside the source root module, so can anyone tell me what am I missing?

edit: Here is a screenshot of the project structure with a bit of code to understand the error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrhAs.png  - If I have the Main Class in the src folder everything works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your image, you have posted I see that you created the package in a wrong source. If you want to create a package (for example "main") where you want to insert a class (for example your Main), you need to do this in default java folder. In your case, it's src folder. Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Added the image

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell the version of java you are using as with latest java version a new feature addition have been made i.e. code can be distributed into modules unlike earlier.

so that could be the issue.

```
module blog { 
         exports com.google.com; 
         requires cms; 
}
```

example of new module feature. So have you broken your code like this .pl

Comment: Java 1.8 (if I am not wrong,the module is a 1.9 feuture)